# Problems with CPack building multiple packages at once

Tags: cmake, cpack

I'm facing problems using the packaging with `CPack` and `CMake 3.7.2`.

I try to build three different packages, `MSI` (via `WIX`), `IFW`, and `ZIP`.

According to the documentation I set the following variables in my `CMakeLists.txt` (and a few more which are required):

```
set(CPACK_WIX_ROOT "C:/Temp/WiX-3.10/binaries")
set(QTIFWDIR "${GLOBAL}/Qt/Tools/QtInstallerFramework/2.0/bin")
set(CPACK_GENERATOR "WIX;IFW;ZIP")
```

I'm including `CPack` at the last possible position before any components are defined.

```
<all variables have been defined before this point>
include(CPack)
include(CPackWIX)
include(CPackIFW)

cpack_add_component(AppBinaries DISPLAY_NAME "MyAppBinaries" DESCRIPTION "My Application Binaries")
cpack_ifw_configure_component(AppBinaries VERSION ${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION} SCRIPT "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cpack/installscript.qs")
cpack_add_component(AppDocs DISPLAY_NAME "MyAppDocs" DESCRIPTION "My Application Docs")
cpack_add_component(AppData DISPLAY_NAME "MyAppData" DESCRIPTION "My Application Data")
```

After creating the build dir and running from there

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" ..\TestProject
```

the files `CMakeCache.txt`, `CPackConfig.cmake`, `CPackSourceConfig.cmake`, and `CPackProperties.cmake` are generated.

When running `cpack -C Release` to build all three installers at once, the first one (`WIX`) is built, but the second one (`QtIFW`) fails with the messages

> CPack Error: Cannot find QtIFW compiler "binarycreator": likely it is
>   not installed, or not in your PATH CPack Error: Cannot initialize the
>   generator IFW

I inspected the `CMakeCache.txt` file but found the following entries properly defined:

```
//QtIFW binarycreator command line client
CPACK_IFW_BINARYCREATOR_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=N:/Global/Qt/Tools/QtInstallerFramework/2.0/bin/binarycreator.exe
//QtIFW devtool command line client
CPACK_IFW_DEVTOOL_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=N:/Global/Qt/Tools/QtInstallerFramework/2.0/bin/devtool.exe
//QtIFW installer executable base
CPACK_IFW_INSTALLERBASE_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=N:/Global/Qt/Tools/QtInstallerFramework/2.0/bin/installerbase.exe
//QtIFW repogen command line client
CPACK_IFW_REPOGEN_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=N:/Global/Qt/Tools/QtInstallerFramework/2.0/bin/repogen.exe
//Enable to build 7-Zip source packages
CPACK_SOURCE_7Z:BOOL=ON
//Enable to build ZIP source packages
CPACK_SOURCE_ZIP:BOOL=ON
//Path to a program.
CPACK_WIX_CANDLE_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=C:/Temp/WiX-3.10/binaries/candle.exe
//Path to a program.
CPACK_WIX_LIGHT_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=C:/Temp/WiX-3.10/binaries/light.exe
```

But when I checked the `CPack\*Config.cmake` files none of the entries above are referenced. After running the `cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" ..\TestProject` a second time everything is fine; all those entries are referenced in `CPack\*Config.cmake` files and all three installers can be built.

So I really get stuck at this point.

Any ideas what could be the issue and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out what didn't work as expected. The setting of the `QTIFWDIR` variable is not saved to the `CPack*Config.cmake` files, but the `CMAKE_WIX_ROOT` variable is. Those variables seem to be evaluated at runtime by `CPack`. Therefore the `WIX` build run successfully but the `IFW` build complained about a the missing binarycreator. Adding the variable with its current setting made everything run as expected.

**Follow up:**

According to the maintainer `QTIFWDIR` should be rather an environment variable than a `CMake` variable. And `CPACK_WIX_ROOT` is considered to be an internal `CPack` variable. You need to install `WIX` (and set the `WIX` environment variable manually, if it hasn't already been done by the installation).